# apply JAXB annotation to an existing data model

Tags: java, jaxb

I have the following problem. For webservices I am using an existing data model. So I need to apply JAXB annotations on the existing source classes. This requires a lot of effort to do manually.

Does anyone know a tool that can help automate this process? For clarity, generating java source code through an `xsd` is not the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can first get all classes in your data model package and then use Javassist to do add an annotation on each of those classes at run-time.

- Check out how to get all classes in a package [tutorial](http://www.dzone.com/snippets/get-all-classes-within-package)
- Check out this Javassist [tutorial](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html) about adding annotations at
  runtime

If you want to avoid this procedure though and just change the source code I think Search/Replace in your data model package would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

[**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) is configuration by exception.  This means you only need to annotate the model where the desired representation defers from the default one:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/MOXy/GettingStarted/TheBasics

If you have an XML Schema that you are trying to map your domain model to, then you may find the [Dali](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFgQFjAA&url=http://www.eclipse.org/dali/&ei=J8q0T63QNube2QXTlfEO&usg=AFQjCNE8YOhy5bc2PJGKyx2g1hplAedYsg) JAXB tooling in [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) helpful.  I would recommend trying out a pre-released version of Juno.

Comment: I was not aware that's JSR-222 is by excpetion. Thanks a lot for this input. I think that helps!